# How to draw 2d contour plot in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, matrix, gdi

I'm mainly interested in algorithm which would enable me to convert Point3D[] into drawable gdi lines?

Comment: A Google search provides a reference to Jack Xu's book *Practical C#: Charts and Graphics*. The book can be browsed on [Scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/doc/55469066/Practical-C-Charts-and-Graphics-9780979372506). Starting on page 348, there is an extensive section on (2D) contour charts.

Comment: I've seen that it only shows usage of library , but not it's internal code .

Comment: If I am not mistaken, all code is contained in the book, but you probably need to apply some of the basic classes from the book as well.  The complete code can be downloaded from [here](http://www.drxudotnet.com/), but you are then required to buy a copy of the book as well. Unfortunately, this is the only C# contour chart source I have found.

Comment: Actually, if you can live with WPF code, the example code from Jack Xu's book *Practical WPF Charts and Graphics* can be downloaded for free from [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430224815).

Comment: Thanks I found AddContour method on page 369 it's huge ,but I'll try to do something with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Anders Gustafsson I was able to build something:

```
public partial class FunctionGraph : UserControl
{
    private Rectangle _area = new Rectangle(-10, -10, 20, 20);

    private Func<float, float, float> _func;

    public FunctionGraph()
    {
        SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        this.Padding.All=20;
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public Rectangle Area
    {
        get { return _area; }
        set
        {
            _area = value;

            Invalidate();
        }
    }


    public Func<float, float, float> Function
    {
        get { return _func; }
        set
        {
            _func = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }


    public PointF GraphToClient(PointF p)
    {
        var xreal = this.ClientRectangle.Width - this.Padding.All * 2;
        var yreal = this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Padding.All * 2;
         int n = (this.ClientRectangle.Width-this.Padding.All*2)/5;

            int m = (this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Padding.All *2) / 5;

        return new PointF
                    {
                        X = this.Padding.All+p.X/ (xreal / (n * 5)),
                        Y = this.Padding.All + p.Y / (yreal / (m * 5))
                    };




    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var graphics = e.Graphics;

        if (_func != null && !DesignMode&& Enabled)
        {

            float min = Single.MaxValue;

            float max = Single.MinValue;

            int n = (this.ClientRectangle.Width-this.Padding.All*2)/5;

            int m = (this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Padding.All *2) / 5;

            var pts = new Point3F[n,m];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {




                    var xreal = this.ClientRectangle.Width - this.Padding.All * 2;
                    var yreal = this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Padding.All * 2;


                    var pt=new Point3F(this.Padding.All+i * 5,this.Padding.All+ j * 5, _func((i * 5) * (xreal / (n * 5)), (j * 5) * (yreal / (m * 5))));

                    if (i == n-1)
                        pt.X = this.ClientRectangle.Width - this.Padding.All;
                    if(j==m-1)
                        pt.Y = this.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Padding.All;

                    pts[i, j] = pt;
                    if (pts[i, j].Z > max)
                        max = pts[i, j].Z;
                    if (pts[i, j].Z < min)
                        min = pts[i, j].Z;



                }

            }


            DrawContour(graphics, pts, min, max, 10);
            DrawColor(graphics, pts, min, max);

            var rect = this.ClientRectangle;

            rect.Inflate(-this.Padding.All+1,-this.Padding.All+1);

            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(graphics, rect, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed);

            int stepx = (this.ClientRectangle.Width - 2*this.Padding.All)/_area.Width;
            int stepy = (this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2 * this.Padding.All) / _area.Height;

            for (int i = _area.X; i < _area.Width; i++)
            {
              graphics.DrawString(i.ToString("0.0"),this.Font,Brushes.Black,this.Padding.All+(i-_area.X)*stepx,this.ClientRectangle.Height-this.Padding.All*0.75f);

            }
            using (var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft){Alignment = StringAlignment.Far})
            {
               // graphics.TranslateTransform(this.ClientRectangle.Width,0);
               // graphics.RotateTransform(90);

                for (int i = _area.Y; i < _area.Height; i++)
                {
                    graphics.DrawString(i.ToString("0.0"), this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.Padding.All*0.25f-this.Font.Size*0.5f
                        , this.ClientRectangle.Height-this.Padding.All- (i-_area.Y) * stepy,format);
                }
                graphics.ResetTransform();
            }
        }

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(graphics, ClientRectangle, SystemColors.ActiveBorder, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private struct Point3F
    {
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public float Z { get; set; }


        public Point3F(float x,float y,float z) : this()
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Z = z;
        }

    }

    private static void DrawContour(Graphics g, Point3F[,] pts, float zmin, float zmax, int ncount)
    {
        using (var aPen = new Pen(Color.DimGray) {Width = 0.25f})
        {
            var pta = new PointF[2];


            var zlevels = new float[ncount];
            for (int i = 0; i < ncount; i++)
            {
                zlevels[i] = zmin + i*(zmax - zmin)/(ncount - 1);
            }
            int i0, i1, i2, j0, j1, j2;
            float zratio = 1; // Draw contour on the XY plane:
            for (int i = 0; i < pts.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pts.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < ncount; k++)
                    {
                        // Left triangle:
                        i0 = i;
                        j0 = j;
                        i1 = i;
                        j1 = j + 1;
                        i2 = i + 1;
                        j2 = j + 1;
                        if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z ||
                             zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z) &&
                            (zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                             zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i1, j1].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X, (1 - zratio)*pts[i0, j0].Y + zratio*pts[i1, j1].Y);
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i1, j1].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i1, j1].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF((1 - zratio)*pts[i1, j1].X + zratio*pts[i2, j2].X, pts[i1, j1].Y);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        }
                        else if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z) &&
                                 (zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF((1 - zratio)*pts[i0, j0].X + zratio*pts[i2, j2].X,
                                           (1 - zratio)*pts[i0, j0].Y + zratio*pts[i2, j2].Y);
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i1, j1].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i1, j1].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF((1 - zratio)*pts[i1, j1].X + zratio*pts[i2, j2].X, pts[i1, j1].Y);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        }
                        else if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z) &&
                                 (zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i1, j1].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X, (1 - zratio)*pts[i0, j0].Y + zratio*pts[i1, j1].Y)
                                ;
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].X*zratio,
                                           pts[i0, j0].Y*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].Y*zratio);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        } // right triangle:
                        i0 = i;
                        j0 = j;
                        i1 = i + 1;
                        j1 = j;
                        i2 = i + 1;
                        j2 = j + 1;
                        if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z ||
                             zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z) &&
                            (zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                             zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i1, j1].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X*(1 - zratio) + pts[i1, j1].X*zratio, pts[i0, j0].Y);
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i1, j1].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i1, j1].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF(pts[i1, j1].X, pts[i1, j1].Y*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].Y*zratio);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        }
                        else if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z) &&
                                 (zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].X*zratio,
                                           pts[i0, j0].Y*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].Y*zratio);
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i1, j1].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i1, j1].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF(pts[i1, j1].X, pts[i1, j1].Y*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].Y*zratio);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        }
                        else if ((zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i1, j1].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i1, j1].Z) &&
                                 (zlevels[k] >= pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] < pts[i2, j2].Z ||
                                  zlevels[k] < pts[i0, j0].Z && zlevels[k] >= pts[i2, j2].Z))
                        {
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i1, j1].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[0] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X*(1 - zratio) + pts[i1, j1].X*zratio, pts[i0, j0].Y);
                            zratio = (zlevels[k] - pts[i0, j0].Z)/(pts[i2, j2].Z - pts[i0, j0].Z);
                            pta[1] =
                                new PointF(pts[i0, j0].X*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].X*zratio,
                                           pts[i0, j0].Y*(1 - zratio) + pts[i2, j2].Y*zratio);
                            g.DrawLine(aPen, pta[0], pta[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Color GetColor(float value, float maxValue, float minValue)
    {
        // Convert into a value between 0 and 1023.
        int int_value = (int) (1023*(value - maxValue)/(minValue - maxValue));

        // Map different color bands.
        if (int_value < 256)
        {
            // Red to yellow. (255, 0, 0) to (255, 255, 0).
            return Color.FromArgb(255, int_value, 0);
        }
        else if (int_value < 512)
        {
            // Yellow to green. (255, 255, 0) to (0, 255, 0).
            int_value -= 256;
            return Color.FromArgb(255 - int_value, 255, 0);
        }
        else if (int_value < 768)
        {
            // Green to aqua. (0, 255, 0) to (0, 255, 255).
            int_value -= 512;
            return Color.FromArgb(0, 255, int_value);
        }
        else
        {
            // Aqua to blue. (0, 255, 255) to (0, 0, 255).
            int_value -= 768;
            return Color.FromArgb(0, 255 - int_value, 255);
        }
    }

    private static void DrawColor(Graphics g, Point3F[,] pts, float zmin, float zmax)
    {          
        var pta = new PointF[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < pts.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pts.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                pta[0] = new PointF(pts[i, j].X, pts[i, j].Y);
                pta[1] = new PointF(pts[i, j + 1].X, pts[i, j + 1].Y);
                pta[2] = new PointF(pts[i + 1, j + 1].X, pts[i + 1, j + 1].Y);
                pta[3] = new PointF(pts[i + 1, j].X, pts[i + 1, j].Y);
                using (var aBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, GetColor(pts[i, j].Z, zmin, zmax))))
                {
                    g.FillPolygon(aBrush, pta);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you specify an example with example dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTK library contains 3D functions. This is an open-source library for .NET; you can find out more at http://www.opentk.com/doc/math.

If you are interested in interactive graphics or games, check out the XNA library (which you can use to write Xbox 360 and PC games) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise enough.I want to draw 2d contours.