# .NET: How to draw Contours Lines and Filled Contours from grid data

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project where I need to draw contours lines and filled contours. I have generated (X,Y,Z) data series from a algorithm.

Data series generated in **Rows X Columns** grid format e.g **3X3, 50X50** ..

(0,10,0.5), (0, 20, 5), (0, 30, 10)

(1,10,0.5), (1, 20, 5), (1, 30, 10)

(2,10,0.5), (2, 20, 5), (2, 30, 10)

**Drawing of data series grid. (50 X 50)**

[image]

**Software which generated the contours lines from above grid**

[image]

I have searched on it but can't found any precise code. Mostly I have found software's which generate all the things.

I have also tried [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303023/1558544) but doesn't generate correct output.

How can I do this? If there is no solution Please suggest me the learning content.

**Updated: Code Which returns Lines and Polygons.**

```
class Demo
{
    IntPtr M_Pointer_Contour;

    // Filled by another function from grid data
    public double[] CoordX = new double[1000000];
    public double[] CoordY = new double[1000000];

    public void GetPolygons()
    {
        var polygonCount = Contour.ContourGetPolygonsCount(M_Pointer_Contour); // Returns Polygon Count

        for (int i = 0; i < polygonCount; i++)
        {
            int PolgyonVerticesCount;
            double DistanceValue;

            // returns Polygon vertices
            Contour.ContourGetPolygonsParameters(M_Pointer_Contour, i, out PolgyonVerticesCount, out DistanceValue);

            // As per software documentation
            for (int v = 0; v < PolgyonVerticesCount; v++)
            {
                var x = CoordX[i];
                var y = CoordY[i];

                // Adding x,y in list for each polygon
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetPolyLines()
    {
        var polyLineCount = Contour.ContourGetPolylinesCount(M_Pointer_Contour); // Returns Polygon Count

        for (int i = 0; i < polyLineCount; i++)
        {
            int PolyLineVerticesCount;
            double DistanceValue;

            // returns Polygon vertices
            Contour.ContourGetPolylineParameters(M_Pointer_Contour, i, out PolyLineVerticesCount, out DistanceValue);

            // As per software documentation
            for (int v = 0; v < PolyLineVerticesCount; v++)
            {
                var x = CoordX[i];
                var y = CoordY[i];

                // Adding x, y in list for each line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Code output from this code

[image]

Thank you

Comment: @TaW Are you asking for Grid height? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite catch your post. Stil not sure: What exactly is it you need: A routine that __draws/fills__ the contour lines (which is trivial) or one that __finds__ the points that connect to a contour (which is not so trivial)?

Comment: I am looking for contours line data series. Like this software returns me contours line count and (X,Y) series in array e,g LineX[], LineY[]. You can assume list of coordinates of each line.

Comment: I above output I have got 49 Polygons and 51 Lines. Actually I am creating this grid from Kriging algorithm.

Comment: So you already got the polygons that make up the contours? And only want to draw them??

Comment: Yes this is the issue. Software returns me the list of coordinates (X,Y) but these are in unknown forms. Whenever I have tried to draw them in my code it draws the wrong shape.

Comment: OK. Please show the c# declaration of those lists; drawing from those should not be so hard..

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107658/discussion-between-taw-and-askquestion).